# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Firefox'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, attributeerror

Complete rookie here; just trying to open Firefox with this bit of code in a program results in AttributeError as specified in the subject:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

Oddly, entering the code directly in the Python shell line by line works fine. How do I fix it?

Here's the code line by line in IDLE:

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
>>> binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
>>>
```

Running it opens the browser as intended.

Here's the traceback:

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
============== RESTART: C:\Users\Paweł\MyPythonScripts\email.py ==============
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Paweł\MyPythonScripts\email.py", line 4, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Users\Paweł\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Paweł\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 19, in <module>
    import http.client as http_client
  File "C:\Users\Paweł\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "C:\Users\Paweł\MyPythonScripts\email.py", line 8, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Firefox'
>>>
```

Comment: _entering the code directly in the Python shell line by line works fine_ Show us a transcript of this.

Comment: Also show us the complete error traceback from the posted code.

Comment: It looks like you're caught in a circular import loop.  Rename your local `email.py` file to something else, as `lib/http/client.py` is importing it instead of the real system `email` module.

Comment: Alright, it's working now. Renamed it per the suggestion. Thanks a lot!